# C# program doesnt change combo box text

Tags: c#, string, text, combobox

I tell the program to change the Combo box text to change to a string i have, and it doesnt change the text.
Here is the part of the code:

```
int i = 0;
bool found = false;
do
{
    if (Globais.loc_txt[i] == (items[0] + " ") || Globais.loc_txt[i] == (items[0]))
    {
        cb_loc.Text = Globais.loc_txt[i]; // ele encontra bem, mas agora nao está a mudar o valor de text na cb
        break;
    }

    else { i++; }

} while (!found && i <= Globais.loc.Length);
```

Regardless, thanks.

PS: cb_loc is the name of my combo box and Globais.loc_txt[i] is a string array and it has a string in the i position.

[image]

Thats my combo box settings or whatever you call them.

Comment: Is your if condition ever true? To test it, debug it or add Debug.WriteLine("Got it"); to the if

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: yes, it runs the code to change the cb_loc value, but then when i see it didnt really changed the text

Comment: yes i debugged it

Comment: Have you tried to add a hardcoded string, like "The new Text" ?

Comment: Is the Combobox DropDownStyle accidentally set to DropDownList ?

Comment: yes, i tried, and it still doesnt change the text

Comment: Yes it is in DropownList, but thats intentional and it doesnt affect what im trying to do

Comment: Please post the declaration of the ComboBox.

Comment: We need the declaration, where you say: cb_loc = combobox..

Comment: what do you mean? this? private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cb_loc; i dont understand  what you want. I created a combo box and named it cb_loc, i dind tmade nothing like cb_loc = combobox

Comment: If the item you found is in fact already IN the combo box, why not just select it?? It will change the text.... just change the selectedindex.

Comment: omg it worked ahaha  nice one @Trey

Comment: Thanks bro, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx):

Setting the Text property to null or an empty string ("") sets the SelectedIndex to -1. Setting the Text property to a value that is in the Items collection sets the SelectedIndex to the index of that item. **Setting the Text property to a value that is not in the collection leaves the SelectedIndex unchanged.**

Is the text you are setting the combobox.Text to not an item in the combobox?
If it is a new string trying adding the item to the collection first.

Your if logic just seems to be comparing a strings and checking it with trailing space. 
 1, I am presuming both are not in your combobox.items. 
 2, Could you just Trim the Globais.loc_txt[i]

```
int i = 0;
bool found = false;
do
{
    string text = Globais.loc_txt[i].TrimEnd()
    if (text == item[0])
    {
        cb_loc.Text = text; // ele encontra bem, mas agora nao está a mudar o valor de text na cb
        break;
    }

    else { i++; }

} while (!found && i <= Globais.loc.Length);
```

Comment: if it enter inside the if stament, it means it found a corresponding match in the array, so that leaves me in the same place i was :/

Comment: Are you saying that the ComboBox.Items should match the Globais.loc_txt[].